# Can I switch perks?

Tags: gloomhaven

Are there rules in Gloomhaven for switching perks?  I read nothing about it in the RuleBook nor saw anything via google.  Wondering if this is the case of doesn't say so can't do it.

As much as one can stress about a game, I am worried picking the wrong thing then later feeling I could have done better.

Comment: You'll get another one each level, so I don't see the point of allowing this. I would definitely be opposed to a house rule allowing this. I would, however, be open to requests on a case by case basis (e.g. I'd be more likely to allow a swap If we're talking about a character that started with a lot of perks).

Comment: If you haven't taken the "Ignore scenario effects" perk, then you need to house-rule a swap ASAP, IMHO. YMMV.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I agree it is not in the rules that you cannot switch perks, but there is also no rule that allows you to switch perks. So I'd lean towards: once you check the box, you are done.

This may be harsh, but Gloomhaven as a legacy game is all about making decisions that you later regret.

That being said if you don't like the fact that you can't change perks, you can always (try to) add a house rule that allows you to.

Comment: Thanks, I was already considering a house rule like "retrain" in 3.5D&D (change but at cost).  I'll give this a couple days to see if anyone has more info then will accept.

Comment: My take on this is that it doesn't really affect the legacy state of the game (a change to the character sheet). As long as you're doing it because you don't like how the perk plays, rather than because you know you're going into a certain style of scenario, then I say allow it if it makes the game more enjoyable for the person doing it. It doesn't really affect anyone else anyway!

Answer (score -3):

Given that there are situations that cause you to lose perks (you can lose "checkmarks" on occasion, and if you only have enough to have just earned a perk, that perk then goes away).

That to me, is the "in" to allowing for a perk change.  Given I can lose a checkmark, lose a perk because of it, and then ... when I "re-earn" the perk pick a completely different one ... why can't I just change them on the spot?

Although, I agree with the poster who said "no changing perks if you have advance knowledge of a scenario".

Comment: This is incorrect, p.42 of the rules "A character can never lose a checkmark that would cause him or her to lose a perk"

Comment: Lol.  Teach me to blindly trust the guy with the rulebook ;-)